# Making lists with different values Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, list, set, unique

I am trying to make two different lists with different values to each other, so that none of the values are the same. After trying numerous times and failing, I wanted to ask for help.

Currently, this is the code I use to generate each list, with different values within themselves. I would like any of intercepting values to be changed, so that they are no longer intercepting. I would also like none of the lists to contain the value of "player". Thanks in advance

```
list1= set()
list2= set()
player = 0,0

while len(list1) != 6:
    item1 = (random.randint(0,5),random.randint(0,5))
    list1.add(item1)
while len(list2) != 6:
    item2 = (random.randint(0,5),random.randint(0,5))
    list2.add(item2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if the `item2` is already in the `list1`, and ignore it if it is. Check if `itemx` is equal to `player` and ignore it as well if it is.

```
import random

list1 = set()
list2 = set()
player = 0, 0

while len(list1) != 6:
    item1 = (random.randint(0, 5), random.randint(0, 5))
    if item1 == player:
        continue

    list1.add(item1)

while len(list2) != 6:
    item2 = (random.randint(0, 5), random.randint(0, 5))
    if (item2 == player) or (item2 in list1):
        continue

    list2.add(item2)

print list1
print list2
```

Comment: Thank you, it was much simpler than expected

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no item should appear twice (on both lists) and assuming the number of items is small, generate all the permutations and choose randomly two sequences:

```
from itertools import product
from random import shuffle

player = (0, 0)

# Generate all possible pairs or [0-5]x[0-5]
values = [pair for pair in product(range(5), repeat=2)) if pair != player]

# Randomize the order to the pairs
shuffle(values)

# Take the first six to the first list
list1 = values[:6]
# Take the next six to the second list
list2 = values[6:12]
```

Comment: Does this solution take in account that the `player` value should not be in the lists?

Answer (score 0):

I would use if loop

```
import random

list1 = set()
list2 = set()
player = 0, 0

while len(list1) != 6:
    item1 = (random.randint(0, 5), random.randint(0, 5))         // setup list1 first
    list1.add(item1)

while len(list2) != 6:
    item2 = (random.randint(0, 5), random.randint(0, 5))         // setup list2
    if item2 not in list1:                                       // checks if value item2 not in list1. If not, adds item2 to list2
       list2.add(item2)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you'd like to check against both lists:

```
import random

list1 = set()
list2 = set()
player = (0, 0)

while len(list1) != 6:
    item1 = (random.randint(0, 5), random.randint(0, 5))
    item2 = (random.randint(0, 5), random.randint(0, 5))
    if item1 != player and item1 not in list1 and item1 not in list2 and item2 != player and item2 not in list1 and item2 not in list2:
        list1.add(item1)
        list2.add(item2)

print(list1)
print(list2)
```